# Linux subsystem for Windows - shell script scp is renaming all files to "."

Tags: bash, shell, scp, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a simple shell script consisting of one line:

scp user@:/home/user/folder/subfolder/* ./destFolder/

When I run this one line in my Linux shell it runs fine, it copies all of the files into my destFolder directory.  But when I run it as a script, it leaves me with one file named "." in my destFolder directory.  I still see the output from scp, as if it's copying all of the files over and just saving them all as ".", overwriting it over and over again.  All of the files are 25KB in size, and the leftover "." file is also 25KB in size.

I'm really not understanding why it's not working, or working differently for that matter, when I enter it directly in the shell vs use that same shell to run this script.

Comment: Offtopic: but i think you schould ask that question on Superuser: https://superuser.com/

Comment: `.` is a special directory meaning the "current directory". It should always exists and is not a real file.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was.  The text editor I was using was adding CRLF at the end of each line.  Apparently Linux subsystem for Windows interprets the CR as the characters: '/r', instead of ignoring the CR as Linux usually does.  This was causing the files to all be named '$'r'', which  Windows displayed as: ..

Comment: Well, yes, CRLF means *Carriage Return* and *Line Feed* being `'\r'` and `'\n'`.